# Crear esta forma con css

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo crear esta forma con css solamente, he intentado crear la imagen directamente con css, al principio modifique el border-radius pensando que esto podría crear el efecto del medio

```
border-radius: 170%;
```

Pero eso no funciono me creaba la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces solo lo redondee, he intente con after y before, pero resulta que tampoco funciona, existe o conocen una forma de hacerlo con css únicamente

Para volver la pregunta mas clara, agregare lo que he probado.

/*Div central (el que tiene el borde azul y se espera que sea como la forma de muestra)*/

```
#U2L5ParagraphQuestion
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 3%;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    border-radius: 11vw;
    font-family: Lato-ligth;
    border: 4px solid #2b3098;
    box-shadow: 4px 3px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

#U2L5ParagraphQuestion:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

#U2L5ParagraphQuestion:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

Como pueden apreciar, estoy utilizando componentes before y after para tratar de crear la forma, aún no se da.

Comment: puedes darle una ojeada a este enlace trae muchas formas hechas con css talvez una te pueda ayudar a lo que necesitas https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: ¿Tienes un enlace a algún sitio donde tengan esa forma? O solo tienes la imagen

Comment: @AlejoFlorez por favor, incluye lo que hayas intentado en la propia pregunta. De ese modo podremos ayudarte a encontrar un posible error o nos ahorraremos intentar algo que ya probaste. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] en el centro de ayuda. También nos ayudaría saber cuál es tu HTML o el CSS que tengas hasta el momento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es así como lo haría con CSS: El div tiene border-radius:1em; y los pseudo elementos before y after son unos cuadrados girados unos 45deg. Em lugar de ponerle un `border` estoy utilizando `filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #00f)`. Si cambias el font-size del body a 50px podrás ver que no es perfecto. Yo utilizaría SVG.

```css
body{font-size:20px}


.so{
width:19em; 
height:2.5em;
padding:1em; 
margin:1em auto; 
border-radius:1em;
position:relative;
background:white;
filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #00f)
}

.so::before,
.so::after{
  content:"";
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
  left:-1.12em;
  top:1em;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background:white;
  z-index:-1;
  width:2.5em; height:2.5em;}

.so::after{
  left:19.64em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="so">Debo crear esta forma con css solamente, he intentado crear la imagen directamente con css</div>
```

Así es como lo puedes hacer utilizando SVG:

```css
svg{border:1px solid #d9d9d9;width:450px;font-size:18px;}
path{fill:none;stroke:blue;stroke-width:3px}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 450 100">
  <path d="M5,50 
           Q5,50 11.644,42.526
           L38.356,12.474 
           Q45,5 55.000,5.000
           L395.000,5.000 
           Q405,5 411.644,12.474
           L445,50 
           Q445,50 438.356,57.474
           L411.644,87.526 
           Q405,95 395.000,95.000
           L55.000,95.000 
           Q45,95 38.356,87.526Z"
        />
  
  <text x="50" y="40">
    Debo crear esta forma con css solamente, he 
  </text>
  <text x="50" y="70">
    intentado crear la imagen directamente con css
  </text>
  <svg>
```

Comment: Sos un crack, Muchas gracias